# Función merge left - conservar todos las filas de base datos x y asignar valores repetidamente desde una columna de la base de datos y

Tags: r

Tengo una base de datos x con columna id con valores repetidos y quiero conservar todas las filas de x y que no se añadan nuevas filas cuando uso merge.

La base de datos y son solo dos columnas, id y la columna con los valores que quiero asignar.

Data frame x

| Id | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | x |
| 2 | A | X |
| 2 | B | Y |
| 3 | A | Y |
| 3 | C | X |
| 6 | C | Z |

Data frame y

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 3 |

Resultado que quiero obtener:

Data frame new

| Id | c1 | c2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | x | 10 |
| 2 | A | X | 9 |
| 2 | B | Y | 9 |
| 3 | A | Y | 7 |
| 3 | C | X | 7 |
| 6 | C | Z | 7 |

Estoy usando la siguiente función merge (left join) pero obtengo muchas mas filas de las esperadas:
Merge(data x, data y, by: “Id”, all.x=True)

Alguna idea de cómo debería hacer la unión usando merge?

Muchísimas gracias por adelantado

###### Mucha gracias! Mis datos tenían valores repetidos id también en la tabla y ! Como se pueden reducir a valores únicos y crear nuevas columnas para cada valor? (Sin usar deploy)

He creado una lista con aggregate () que da el siguiente resultado:

Tabla y original

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 |

Resultado:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10,9 |
| 2 | 7,7 |
| 3 | 4,2,3 |

Como puedo obtener 3 columnas por cada id, una para cada valué?

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo está perfecto, me imagino que el problema es que tienes casos con más de una fila en `y`. ¿Qué es lo que quisieras en dicho caso?

Comment: Muchas gracias  , exactamente lo he comprobado y tenia datos duplicados en ambas  tablas de datos. En la tabla y tengo 3 o 4 datos por cada id. Ahora  he intentado separar la tabla de datos y, dejando valores únicos en id y creando 3 o cuatro columnas por cada fila; pero no ha sido fácil y lo único que he conseguido (usando funcion aggregate) es crear una lista con una columna en la que están los 3 o 4 datos separados por comas. Ahora no se como puedo convertir la lista en una tabla de datos; rellenando con valores NA cuando sólo hay 3 datos por id.  [no puedo usar la librería deploy)